# Android: Play / Pause song on proximity sensor method

Tags: android

Is there any way to play and pause the song using proximity sensor? I wanted to play the song as default state. When a user waves his hand over the proximity sensor, it should pause the song till the time he waves again.

I have these code which pause when you in near / far state. It start playing on far / near value. 
I wanted to make is pause for the same event and then play for the same event next time.

```
            if(event.values[0]==sensor.getMinDelay()) or sensor.getMaximumRange()
            {   
                Log.i("Pause","Pause");
                player.pause();
                textView.setText("Pause");

            }
            else
            {   
                Log.i("Play","Play");
                player.start();
                textView.setText("Now Playing..!"); 
            }
```

Any help / Suggestions is appreciated.